# Scroll for qgis custom form

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I made form in qt designer for QGIS. But there are a lot of fields in It and It can't placed in screen. I want to add scroll area in my qt designer form but It doesn't work as scroll doesn't appear.
Maybe I do something wrong?

[image]